# How to get rid of incoming commits after doing a git Reset in Visual Studio? (Delete remote commits)

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio

I am trying to use the Visual Studio team explorer which is under Git. However, when I click [image]

this and I can go back to my previous version, it unable to because there is incoming commits back to where the latest wrong version again...

[image]

I tried to click revert and does not help me to going back to the previous version again. Can anyone help how to going back to previous version without have incoming commit?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have just done a revert to one commit and now have several unwanted incoming commits.

Comment: @ProfK You probably haven't done a revert, instead you most likely have done a reset and now your local branch is behind the remote branch and there are several incoming commits. Usually you need to revert those commits. But of for some reason, you want to get rid of them without having them in history (WARNING), then you can reset them and delete changes, then do a force push to overwrite remote commit history.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I meant to say I had done a `reset`, thanks.

Answer (score 30):

You need to [enable force push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-config?tabs=visual-studio&view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#enable-push---force) and then do a force push.

To do so, after doing a reset (delete changes):

- Go to Team Explorer → Settings → Git → Global Settings and check `Enable push --force` and click on `Update` button.
- Go to Team Explorer → Branches → Right click on your local branch and choose `Push`
- A message box will appear showing a warning asking you would you like to overwrite remote commits? Select `Yes`.

> **Warning**
>
> Usually you need to revert changes which simply means undo changes and
> commit this undo as well. So you have both the change and the undo
> commit in history.
>
> But sometimes for some reason, you want to get rid of few last commits
> without having them in remote history (WARNING). So you can reset
> those few commits and delete changes. Now your local branch is behind
> the remote branch and there are several incoming commits. Then you can
> do a force push to overwrite remote commit history by your local
> history.
>
> Do this carefully, just when you understand what you are doing, is overwriting remote history. Don't do it on a branch which is shared between multiple people.

Comment: Thank you, I had found out by Googling that a `push --force` on the command line. I prefer that to setting VS to always push, but thanks for the detail how to.

Comment: @Profk Cool! No problem :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to change a commit message that I'd already pushed to remote. It defeats the purpose to tidy up the commit message if you have to have 2 extra commits for it, so my process was: reset KEEPing changes (to previous commit before the wanted changes), put in the correct commit message, commit, and then push - Note, I did not have force push option until I clicked Push - then I was prompted to choose Fetch Then Push or Force Push.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really revert your changes once committed without having incoming changes.

You can create a patch for the commit you want to go and push the changes of that patch to cancel it out.