# git stash failed when trying to perform a git pull

Tags: git, github

I am trying to run a `git pull` but it fails as follows

```
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:MyOrg/my-repo
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: stash failed

$ git stash pop
No stash entries found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: git has some debugging options : try setting `GIT_TRACE=1 git stash` or `GIT_TRACE2=1 git stash`

Answer (score 1):

for me, that was a `git-crypt` issue

if you are using git-crypt in your repo then follow these steps

`git-crypt lock`

`git merge master`

`git-crypt unlock`

Answer (score 0):

The error message "fatal: stash failed" indicates that the Git command `git stash` failed during the `git pull` operation. However, when you tried to use `git stash pop` afterward, it reported that no stash entries were found. This situation can occur if there was an issue while creating or applying a stash.

To troubleshoot the problem, you can try the following steps:

1. Verify if there are any uncommitted changes in your local repository. Use the command `git status` to check if there are modified files. If there are any changes, commit or discard them before attempting the `git pull` again.
2. Ensure that you have the latest version of Git installed on your system. You can check the Git version by running `git --version`. If you have an outdated version, consider updating Git to the latest stable release.
3. Try using the `git fetch` command instead of `git pull` to fetch the latest changes from the remote repository without applying them immediately. Then, use `git merge` or `git rebase` to apply the changes to your local branch. For example:

   $ git fetch origin master
   $ git merge origin/master
4. If the issue persists, it's possible that there is a problem with the stash stack. You can try clearing the stash stack by running `git stash clear`. Please note that this will permanently remove all stashed changes, so make sure you don't have any important changes stored in the stash. After clearing the stash, you can attempt the `git pull` operation again.

If none of the above steps resolve the problem, it may be helpful to provide additional information about the specific context and any error messages that occur during the `git pull` operation.

Comment: `git stash clear` didn't do the trick. I ended up doing a [git push force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295374/how-to-get-rid-of-incoming-commits-after-doing-a-git-reset-in-visual-studio-de)

Comment: I'm trying to run git merge master and that error popup 
already tried those listed steps